# How to proceduraly create instances of a class

Tags: python, class

So im trying to make  instances of a class proceduraly for a program that is going to run in minecraft: pi edition

The only problem im having is that I (think I) need to make a different instance of a class for each mob/block, but I cant find anyway to create class instances prodecuraly, so It will make instance "Mob0" for the first one and then "Mob1" for the second.

Using variables to combine Mob and a number does work however as it just resets the variables to a class instance

Any help is appreciated, or other ways to do the same thing

Comment: Use a list of Mob objects

Comment: @juanpa-arrivillaga, could you maybe explain how this will work? How will creating a list of mob objects allow me to store vec3 position, fall amount, ect. for each mob?

Answer (score 0):

Well that took me a bit, and this is now going to be forgotten, maybe help a random newbie to python in the future

Anyways, I didn't realise that arrays are heterogeneous, and can store instances of a class.

If your reading this you should be able to figure it out from there.